# jQuery - How do I make sure a user enters text before performing any other operations?

Tags: jquery

I'm allowing users to create folders in my app. Once the user clicks on the "New Folder" icon, I display a folder with a text box for the user to enter the name of the folder.

How do I make sure that the user enters a name before clicking on the "New Folder" icon again or for that matter before using my application for anything else?

I tried the input change event, but that offcourse, fires only when the user attempts to enter the name.

```
$(".new-folder-name").change(function () {
      var newFolderName = $(".new-folder-name").val();
    if (newFolderName == "") {
        alert("Please enter a name for the new folder.");
    } else {
        alert("Good, you entered a name: " + newFolderName);
    }
});
```

But what if the user just leaves the text box blank and goes on doing other things with the app?

How can I force the user to enter text first before doing anything else?

Comment: You could make a modal popup.  But this is really a design decision, not a programming one.

Comment: Don't let them do other things in the app if the input isn't valid.

Comment: @KevinB, that's exactly what I'm looking to do. The question is, how?

Comment: @neuDev33 uh.... if ( input.value != "" ) do stuff? all you have to do is either disable everything but the input until it is valid, or prevent everything if the input isn't valid. Your choice, but we aren't going to provide the code for you.

Comment: @KevinB, well, I can't do if (input.value != "") doStuff in every place where the user can do stuff. There could be multiple buttons on my app the user could click. I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You could do that actually, it would be a valid way of solving this. You could even abstract that behind a function so that it's DRY. I don't think you need to be pointed in any direction, you already know what you need to do... You need to prevent the user from doing anything until the input has a valid value. How you do that is a design decision, not a programming problem.

Comment: Well, I agree that you could do that. However, if I understand this right, every time there'd be new stuff, I'd have to remember to add this check there, easy to miss. And, i think it is a programming problem as far as jQuery is concerned.

Comment: Not if you simply delegate a focus event that checks if the input is valid, and if it isn't resets focus back to the name input. since it's delegated, it would automatically affect new inputs that you may add later. That would be yet another *design* decision. You have no error, you have no functionality that is working incorrectly, you have no problem. There is nothing to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Force User Input**
After:

```
alert("Please enter a name for the new folder.");
```

add:

```
setTimeout(function() {$(".new-folder-name").focus();},10);
```

Forces focus on the textbox.

Also, change it from .change() to .blur()

**Modal Popup**
There are several options out there.  Just put your textbox in a modal popup and don't let them close it until they enter something valid.

Comment: Modal popup is preferable simply because it *implies* what is *expected*.  Forcing the focus back to the input isn't the best idea--UI-wise

Comment: adding the modal is not an option for me. Let me try the focus() with settimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Richard said use a modal.

In [twitter-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals) you have that and other tools.